# How to set index for array in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know if we can set an index for an array in PHP like this:

```
$myNum[20];
```

In C, C++, Java we can say `int myNum[20] = {0};`

Comment: You can just `Boldly Go` and give it a try.

Comment: Have a browse through this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Arrays in PHP are not a fixed size, you do not have to define them at a max size, they grow and shrink dynamically [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can set any index in array like this:

```
 $muNum = array();
 $myNum['20'] = "Test";  // here 20 is index
 // OR
 $myNum[20] = "Test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, like this:

```
$var = array();
$var['your_index'] = 1;
$var[10] = 2;
```

Or you can create an empty object like this:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
```

And create properties in this way:

```
$obj->your_index = 1;
$obj->{10} = 2;
```

Just check here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Possibly because your answer does not relate to the actual question. The question is about most languages having fixed size arrays i.e. they must be defined as `$myNum[20];` and they will only have a max 20 occurances, but in PHP that is not the case

Comment: It wasn't made clear that this was the exact nature of the question

Comment: It was not my DV so thats only a guess. It was quite obvious to me what the question was about

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is about the requirement in most languages to defining arrays to the size you want them.

In PHP this is not necessary, arrays are dymanic, they can grow and shrink at will.

So in fact doing `$myNum[20];` to define an array with a set size is almost never done. Also arrays are not typed, you can store different data types in one array.

```
// define an array
$myArr = array();
// load occ 0
$myArr[] = 'Fred';
// load occ 1
$myArr[] = 2;
// load occ 99
$myArr[99] = 'Magic';
// non numeric occurance
$myArr['Assoc'] = 'Array';
```

Would give yo an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Fred
    [1] => 2
    [99] => Magic
    [Assoc] => Array
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr[4]="any1";
$arr[]="any2";
$arr[19]="any3";
$arr[]="any4";
$arr[3]="any5";
$arr[]="any6";
$arr[4]="any7";
$arr[]="any8";
$arr["k"]="any9";
$arr[]="any10";
```

Array have hidden LastMaxmAutoIndex == 23. So, you can shift start index to bigger val, but can't backward.

```
array(9) {
  [4]  => "any7"
  [5]  => "any2"
  [19] => "any3"
  [20] => "any4"
  [3]  => "any5"
  [21] => "any6"
  [22] => "any8"
  ["k"]=> "any9"
  [23] => "any10"
}
```